# Perform Animation on Property Change

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a `ContentControl` which has  a Property `Content`. I wish to animate when the property content changes

**Actual Senario**

**XAML**

```
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentPage}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeVM}">
                        <view:SomeView />
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeOtherVM}">
                        <view:SomeOtherView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
     </ContentControl>
```

Now I Wish to `Fade Out` the Current Content when the Property `CurrentPages`

Also id Possible `Fade In` in the New Page.

Value of CurrentPage can be any thing so i wish if that changes then the Tow animation Kick in...

Any help in this direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use this [attached behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF)

```
public class AnimatedSwitch : DependencyObject
{
    // Define the attached properties      
    public static DependencyProperty BindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Binding", typeof(object), typeof(AnimatedSwitch),
        new PropertyMetadata(BindingChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty PropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Property", typeof(string), typeof(AnimatedSwitch));

    public static object GetBinding(DependencyObject e)
    {
        return e.GetValue(BindingProperty);

    }

    public static void SetBinding(DependencyObject e, object value)
    {
        e.SetValue(BindingProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetProperty(DependencyObject e)
    {
        return (string)e.GetValue(PropertyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetProperty(DependencyObject e, string value)
    {
        e.SetValue(PropertyProperty, value);
    }
    // When the value changes do the fadeout-switch-fadein      
    private static void BindingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard fadeout = new Storyboard();
        var fadeoutAnim = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 0, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)) };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeoutAnim, d);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeoutAnim, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
        fadeout.Children.Add(fadeoutAnim);
        fadeout.Completed += (d1, d2) =>
        {
            var propName = GetProperty(d);
            if (propName != null)
            {
                var prop = d.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
                var binding = GetBinding(d);
                prop.SetValue(d, binding, null);
            }
            Storyboard fadein = new Storyboard();
            var fadeinAnim = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 1, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)) };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeinAnim, d);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeinAnim, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
            fadein.Children.Add(fadeinAnim);
            fadein.Begin();

        };
        fadeout.Begin();
    }
}
```

Then

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0"  
     yourNamespace:AnimatedSwitch.Binding="{Binding CurrentPage}"   
     yourNamespace:AnimatedSwitch.Property="Content">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeVM}">
                    <view:SomeView />
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeOtherVM}">
                    <view:SomeOtherView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
 </ContentControl>
```